# Why can I transform the regular expression 1*0 + 1*0(0+1)*(0+1) to 1*0(0+1)*?

Tags: regex, finite-automata

I can't quite understand, why I can transform the regex `1*0 + 1*0(0+1)*(0+1)` to `1*0(0+1)*`. Anyone able to help me?

Comment: Why do you think you couldn't? Maybe try some example strings and see how they match either.

Comment: If you just want to understand your pattern, try Regex 101 (https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I've see the automata, thus I know it accepts the same strings. My Problem is mostly why `(0+1)` at the end can be left out as it means that there **has** to be another `0` or `1` at the end while `(0+1)*` means that there **might** be another `0` or `1` but don't **has** to be

Comment: Yes, I don't think the transformation is valid either. The second regex matches `0`, the first one doesn't. If the second regex had a `+` at the end instead of a `*`, then I guess they are equivalent.

Comment: No, it is valid as it's `1*0` at the very beginning of the first one which means that it'll accept a single `0` following `+` or `|` which means **or** not **and** and it either evaluates the left part of the expression or the right one..

Comment: Oh, so the `+` is actually a `|` in some (but not all?) cases?

Comment: I think the original regex is: `1*0 or 1*0(0+1)*(0+1)` @EviLGaMer can you confirm?

Comment: For one thing the first regex has spaces and the second doesn't.

Comment: The `+` is always a `|` or  `or`. Guess it's either definition or just the way my professor teaches it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the law of distributivity:

```
  (1*0)+(1*0(0+1)*(0+1))
= (1*0ε)+(1*0(0+1)*(0+1))
= (1*0)(ε+(0+1)*(0+1))
```

and then apply the definition of the the Kleene star `a* = ε+a*a`:

```
= (1*0)((0+1)*)
= 1*0(0+1)*
```